# How to reduce the gray-line artifacts in three.js isosurface rendering of 3D texture example?

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, raycasting, webgl2

the isosurface example in the three.js website shows gray-line artifacts over the surface, please see

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl2_materials_texture3d.html

the glsl shader source code is here

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/shaders/VolumeShader.js#L183-L219

I am wondering if there is a way to reduce or remove such artifact? I tried changing some of the shader parameters, such as `REFINEMENT_STEPS`, `dstep`, but it seems there is no impact.

[image]

Comment: I don't see that...

Comment: I was referring to the vertical gray-line stripes you can see all over my attached screenshot, especially over purple colored vessels, such as the one on right-top corner, and the section near the left edge.

Comment: I know that... :) but still I don't have them...

Comment: can you be more clear? you don't have it when you browse the three.js example directly? can you see it in my attached screenshot?

Comment: Unable to add an image to a comment. If I really try, I can see purple _lines_ there, but I think it's supposed to be like that...right? I don't notice your _purple stripes_ at all. Weird...